# Draw a gesture control resizable circle in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cgrect

I want to draw a circle in iOS. It can be an image view or view, I want to adjust its size on gestures. Like, dragging from outside to the center, the radius of the circle should reduce and so vice versa.

Please note that I want to fix the position of that view, circle or image. I just want to adjust the size as it is dragged.

Comment: You want 1) a way to display a circle and 2) a way to control its radius. I'd go for `CAShapeLayer` + `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: Hi Cyrille, Can you help me in getting its code?

Comment: I (and many others here) won't write code for you. You have to do a little research first, try things with the directions we give you, and come back with precise questions about why a particular line of code doesn't work. First, you have to try to resize a plain, square `UIView` with a pan gesture recognizer.

Comment: Dear Cryille, I know that it can be done with those classes but I have no idea how to do that. So I asked as this portal is meant for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  - (IBAction)pinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    double scale=[sender scale];
  self.view1.frame=CGRectMake(self.view1.frame.origin.x*scale,     self.view1.frame.origin.y*scale, self.view1.frame.size.width*scale, self.view1.frame.size.height*scale);

[self.view1.layer setCornerRadius:5];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
- (IBAction)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    for (CALayer *layer in self.imageView.layer.sublayers) {
    [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
    CGPoint scale =[sender locationInView:sender.view];

    CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    [circleLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [_imageView bounds].size.width,
                                  [_imageView bounds].size.height)];
    [circleLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX([_imageView bounds]),CGRectGetMidY([_imageView bounds]))];

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(_imageView.frame)+scale.x, CGRectGetHeight(_imageView.frame)+scale.y)];

    [circleLayer setPath:[path CGPath]];

    [circleLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];

    [circleLayer setLineWidth:1.0f];
    [circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];


    [[_imageView layer] addSublayer:circleLayer];

   }
```

Comment: Thanks Johny but it would be better if you could show me how to implement it on UIPanGestureRecognizer rather than pinch. Moreover, can we set it bounds so that the largest size of it may not cross the view?

Comment: Recreate a layer on **every** pinch callback? That's a huge waste of resources.

Comment: m just telling him what to do he can keep initialization some where else.

Comment: Johny's idea works for my stuff. If you know any other way Cyrille then kindly teach me how to make that happen as Johny did rather than giving suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for appreciation.

Comment: You are welcome Johny. Do you have any idea how to set its bounds so that when we enlarge that it may not cross the view on which I am drawing that?

Comment: Thank you Johny. Have you found the solution?

Comment: i edit my answer with pan gesture please try that on

Comment: for setting bounds we have to check layer bounds with screen sizes or your custom view bounds.